# Import certificate to the Group Policy store with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, import, certificate, pfx, group-policy

I am building ARM-templates to set up test-environments in Azure. I am using DSC to set up the different machines. One thing I want to automate is to import a certificate to the group-policies. You can do it like this manually on the domain-controller (Active-Directory server):

- Group Policy Management -> Forest: mydomain.net -> Domains -> mydomain.net -> Group Policy Objects -> Default Domain Policy
- Right click -> Edit
- Default Domain Policy -> Computer Configuration -> Policies -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Public Key Policies -> Trusted Root Certification Authorities
- Right click -> Import

I have laborated with Import-PfxCertificate, CertUtil.exe and .NET C# to accomplish it but haven’t succeeded. What I have tested you can see below, I have put some comments about my thoughts.

**Can anyone help me? How should I do this?**

First we create a certificate and export it and finally we delete it (we keep the exported one):

```
$certificateStoreLocation = "CERT:\LocalMachine\My";
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "P@ssword12" -Force -AsPlainText;

$certificate = New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation $certificateStoreLocation -DnsName "Test-Certificate";

$certificateLocation = "$($certificateStoreLocation)\$($certificate.Thumbprint)";

$result = Export-PfxCertificate -Cert $certificateLocation -FilePath "C:\Data\Certificates\Test-Certificate.pfx" -Password $password;

Get-ChildItem $certificateLocation | Remove-Item;
```

**List the certificate stores**

```
foreach($item in Get-ChildItem "CERT:\")
{
    Write-Host " - CERT:\$($item.Location)\";

    foreach($store in $item.StoreNames.GetEnumerator())
    {
        Write-Host "   - CERT:\$($item.Location)\$($store.Name)";
    }
}
```

**PowerShell – Import-PfxCertificate**

```
$certificateStoreLocation = "CERT:\LocalMachine\Root";
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "P@ssword12" -Force -AsPlainText;

Import-PfxCertificate -CertStoreLocation $certificateStoreLocation -FilePath "C:\Data\Certificates\Test-Certificate.pfx" -Password $password;

Get-ChildItem $certificateStoreLocation;

# Now you can find the certificate in the MMC Certificate Snapin:
# [Console Root\Certificates (Local Computer)\Trusted Root Certification Authorities\Certificates]

# Now you can find the certificate in the registry.
# Get-ChildItem "REGISTRY::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\Root\Certificates\";

# I want to put the certificate here:
# Get-ChildItem "REGISTRY::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\Root\Certificates\";
```

**PowerShell – CertUtil**

```
CertUtil -p "P@ssword12" -ImportPfx "Root" "C:\Data\Certificates\Test-Certificate.pfx";

Get-ChildItem "CERT:\LocalMachine\Root";

CertUtil -p "P@ssword12" -ImportPfx -GroupPolicy "Root" "C:\Data\Certificates\Test-Certificate.pfx"; # No error but the same result as CertUtil -p "P@ssword12" -ImportPfx "Root" "C:\Data\Certificates\Test-Certificate.pfx".
```

**.NET C#**

```
using(var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\Data\Certificates\Test-Certificate.pfx", "P@ssword12"))
{
    // We only have StoreLocation.CurrentUser and StoreLocation.LocalMachine.
    // Can I use System.Management.Automation.Security.NativeMethods+CertStoreFlags.CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_LOCAL_MACHINE_GROUP_POLICY
    // somehow to create/open a store by calling new X509Store(IntPtr storeHandle).

    using (var store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.LocalMachine))
    {
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
        store.Add(certificate);
    }
}
```

**My imaginary solution**

Thought this was a possible solution:

1. Import the certificate to “CERT:\LocalMachine\Root”
2. Move the registry-key “HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\Root\Certificates\THUMBPRINT” to “HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\Root\Certificates\THUMBPRINT”
3. Restart the machine

The registry-keys get correct but the localmachine-root-certificate is still in the certificate-mmc-snapin and no root-certificate is found in the Group Policy Management console.

```
$certificateRegistryKeyPathPrefix = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\Root\Certificates\";
$certificateStoreLocation = "CERT:\LocalMachine\Root";
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "P@ssword12" -Force -AsPlainText;
$pfxCertificatePath = "C:\Data\Certificates\Test-Certificate.pfx";
$policyCertificateRegistryKeyPathPrefix = "HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\Root\Certificates\";

# Get the thumbprint from the pfx-file so we can check if it's already in the registry.
$certificate = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2;
$certificate.Import($pfxCertificatePath, $password, "DefaultKeySet");

$policyCertificateRegistryKeyPath = "$($policyCertificateRegistryKeyPathPrefix)$($certificate.Thumbprint)";

$policyCertificateRegistryKey = Get-Item -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Path $policyCertificateRegistryKeyPath;

if(!$policyCertificateRegistryKey)
{
    $certificateRegistryKeyPath = "$($certificateRegistryKeyPathPrefix)$($certificate.Thumbprint)";

    $certificateRegistryKey = Get-Item -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Path $certificateRegistryKeyPath;

    if(!$certificateRegistryKey)
    {
        $certificate = Import-PfxCertificate -CertStoreLocation $certificateStoreLocation -FilePath $pfxCertificatePath -Password $password;

        $certificateRegistryKey = Get-Item -Path $certificateRegistryKeyPath;
    }

    Move-Item -Destination $policyCertificateRegistryKeyPath -Path $certificateRegistryKeyPath;

    # And then we need to reboot the machine.
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to show that you tried to run and what errors you received.

Comment: BenH: So, I have edited my post. Now I explain more what I have tested.

Comment: @HansKindberg Have you resolved this?

Comment: @Brooke No, I haven't.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to directly modify the registry under the 'Policies' path, create or modify an 'Registry.pol' file to populate it.

You could use the 'PolicyFileEditor' module from the PowerShell Gallery to do this, but the easiest way is to use the native GroupPolicy module to create and set a Registry.pol file as part of a domain GPO, which will also push out the certificate to member servers.

On a domain controller, import/create a cert so it has a blob value stored in the registry, create a GPO, then run something like the following to configure the GPO (named "DistributeRootCerts" here):

```
$certsGpoName = 'DistributeRootCerts'

$certThumbprint = '3A8E60952E2CDB7A31713258468A8F0C7FB3C6F6'

$certRegistryKeyPath = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\MY\Certificates\{0}' -f $certThumbprint

$certBlob = Get-ItemProperty -Path $certRegistryKeyPath -Name 'Blob' | Select -Expand 'Blob'

$certPoliciesRegistryKey = 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\Root\Certificates\{0}' -f $certThumbprint

$null = Set-GPRegistryValue -Name $certsGpoName -Key $certPoliciesRegistryKey -ValueName 'Blob' -Type Binary -Value $certBlob
```

Then you just need to link the GPO into production with 'New-GPLink'.

Comment: Thank you very much Brian. I will try this later. I will be back.